# plusDomains.activities.insert response always 403 access forbidden

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-domains

I give all permission like read, write,login. But i get always response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

Comment: Please show us how to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Are you making the request from a [G Suite](https://gsuite.google.com/) user? (Not a gmail.com user)

Comment: @abraham Any docs about this limitation?

Comment: @Roar "With the Google+ Domains API, Google Apps customers and ISVs can build custom Google+ functionality and services for people who use Google Apps at college, at work, or at home." https://developers.google.com/+/domains/